# Pandas: chunking of a dictionary of dataframes based on time

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, chunks

I have a dictionary of dataframes where each dataframe has price and timestamp columns. something like this `{'A':df1, 'B':df2}`

I need to build a function which can slice up the dataframes inside the dict in chunks of H hours of the timestamp and then pass this dict of dataframes to another function(which does some computation) for every chunk.

How do I go forward with this?

For example

```
def foo(dict_of_dataframes):
    for id, df in dict_of_dataframes.items():
        do_something()

def boo(dict_of_dataframes, chunksize):
    """
    Needs to chunk up the @dict_of_dataframes in @chunksize hours
    and needs to call foo function on these chunks of
    @dicts_of_dataframes
    """
```

Sample data:

```
df1:
Time                       Price
2017-03-07 09:47:31+00:00  100
2017-03-07 11:27:31+00:00  120
2017-03-07 14:47:31+00:00  150
2017-03-07 17:17:31+00:00  135
2017-03-07 20:57:31+00:00  200
2017-03-08 03:27:31+00:00  120
2017-03-08 09:57:31+00:00  100
2017-03-08 11:27:31+00:00  150

df2:
Time                       Price
2017-03-07 09:07:31+00:00  200
2017-03-07 10:27:31+00:00  300
2017-03-07 12:47:31+00:00  100
2017-03-07 17:47:31+00:00  250
2017-03-07 22:27:31+00:00  300
2017-03-08 01:57:31+00:00  500
2017-03-08 02:57:31+00:00  500
2017-03-08 10:27:31+00:00  100
```

I need help with the boo function. How does one go forward with this?

Also is there any specific term for these kinds of boo functions which simulate other function calling. I've seen these a few times, If you could point to a resource which explains how to design these 'function caller' functions, I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: Sample data, sample data, sample data

Comment: Sampling yes, but it needs to pass a whole dictionary of that chunk into the foo function and then pass a second dictionary with the second chunk...
I am not able to understand how to code that part...

Comment: I mean we need sample data to work on the solution. Its expensive to create a dataframe investing time

Comment: @Dark Added some sample data

Comment: You can go for grouping `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='H')` currently cant answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you actually want can be achieved using `resample` - basically a groupby for datetimes. Assuming you need transaction sum within 6 hours, you can use this:

```
def boo(dict_dfs, hours):
    return {k: v.resample(f'{hours}H').sum() for k,v in dict_dfs.items()}
```

now, if you 100% sure you need dicts instead, use `groupby`:

```
def boo(dict_dfs, hours):
    return {k:{hr:v for hr, v in df.groupby(Grouper(key='Time', freq=f'{hours}H'))} for k, df in dict_dfs.items()}
```

Btw, if you want to loop through {key, value} on dicts, use dict.items(), not dict itself.

And one more note: I saw many times people overcomplicating their data structures. Most of the time you don't need dict of dataframes - you can use one dataframe, just having a `category` column or even a multi-index (like, [category, Time] multi-index in your case. With that, you'll get more reusable, fast and clean code!

Comment: Yes, I will use dict.items() sorry for the typo. I really appreciate the list comprehension, but I am unable to understand it... could you please explain what you did here with the group by ? how are you calling the foo function passing the dictionary?

Comment: here `boo` does not execute your `foo` function, just returns dict of chunks for each dataframe in the given dict.

from your example, you should be able to use
foo(boo(ddf, 6) here. 

dict comprehension here just groups each df into chunks and store them as  period: df pair in a new dictionary - one new dict for each dataframe in the initial dictionary